# What is a Killing tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, general-relativity

Wikipedia gives the definition of a [Killing tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_tensor).

Unfortunately, I don't know how to interpret the parentheses (it is also not explicitly explained in the link) and was therefore wondering whether anybody here could help me out?

Comment: It literally says in the link to Symmetric part (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_tensor) that it means that for every permutation of $\alpha, \beta,\gamma$ the term without the parenthesis is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

In local coordinates I think this is $$0 = \nabla_{( \alpha} K_{\beta \gamma)} = \nabla_{\alpha} K_{\beta \gamma} + \nabla_{\gamma} K_{\alpha \beta} + \nabla_{\beta} K_{\gamma \alpha}$$